# How can I negate a regular expression?

Tags: regex, rascal, clair

I want to know a field if it does not match a certain string:

**Case 1:** When the previous node is not `*_pcm.h`, then `l1` gives the path to file `l2`.

**Case 2:** When there is no `l1` or case `1` is not true, then `l` is what I need

```
visit(sec) {
  // case 1
  case \sources(_, "_SOURCES", [*_, l1:\sourceList(_, _, _, p:/_pcm.h/i, _, _),
                l2:\sourceList(_, _, _, n:/_pcm.c/i, _, _), *_]): { 
                    name = determinePath(p, n, f); 
  }
  // case 2
  case \sources(_, "_SOURCES", [*_,  l:\sourceList(_, _, _, n:/_pcm.c/i, _, _) , *_]): {
                    path = getPath(f); 
  }
}
```

Instead of `p:/_pcm.h/i` I tried `p:!/_pcm.h/i` but this does not work

Comment: I don't know this language, but can't you test for a positive match with the regex and then negate the result.

Comment: @JGNI Ditto. `if l1 matches *_pcm.h then whatever else we have path to l2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not directly express this negation inside a pattern, but here is a workaround by adding a `when` condition to the case in the case you are transforming (i.e., using `=>` between pattern and action):

```
data D = d1(str s) | d2(int n);

D transform(D subject){
    return visit(subject){
                case d1(str s) => d1(s + s) when /abc/ !:= s
    }
}
```

In the case of a more complex case, you can to the test and use a `fail` to let the case fail.

```
case d1(str s): { if(/abc/ !:= s) fail; ... }
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I got the desired behavior as follows: case \sources(_, "_SOURCES", [*_, l1:\sourceList(_, _, _, p, _, _), l2:\sourceList(_, _, _, n:/_pcm.c/i, _, _), *_]): { 
     if (/pcm.h/i !:= p) {
      path = getPath(f); 
     } else {
      name = determinePath(p, n, f); 
     }